# Erlang: Read from an input stream in a efficient way

Tags: performance, io, erlang, inputstream, processing-efficiency

I'm writing a program that reads from an **input** stream, i.e.

```
erl -run p main -noshell -s erlang halt < input
```

The problem is that it takes a lot of time to read it (the input stream is huge) using this read function:

```
read_input(L) ->
    case io:get_line("") of
        eof ->
            lists:reverse(L);
        E0 ->
            read_input([E0|L])
    end.
```

I have been looking for more efficient alternatives, but I have found nothing. I have tried to read the file using

```
{ok, Binary} = file:read_file("input")
```

This is by far much more efficient. The problem is that I have to run this program in a platform where the name is unknown so I'd need some alternative to do so. additionally, I can't select the flags used when running, e.g. flag -noinput cannot be added to the command line.

Whatever help you can give will be welcomed.

Comment: If reading the whole file at once is acceptable as you seem to indicate, why not just `{ok, Binary} = file:read_file(InputFile)`? I don't understand the point of using `cat` to copy the input and reading the copy instead.

Comment: Is this a command line application? Will the program always be invoked from the command line like that? Where is the input stream coming from? What is happening to the data after it's read?

Comment: @SteveVinoski I have edited the question to remove the cat thing because it was confusing. Yes I could read it directly from the file, but I don't know its name, so this solution only works while testing.

Comment: @nu-ex Yes, the program should be always used like this, and the input stream read like this. The input comes from the system that will run it (just as it is shown above). The data is processed after. It contains mainly integers so I have to parse them afterwards.

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: @SteveVinoski I don't know the characteristics of the platform. It's a black box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [Steve's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409228/steve-vinoski) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37091420/49197) is fastest known to me solution there can be used `file` module solution with quite good performance:

```
-module(p).

-export([start/0]).

-define(BLK_SIZE, 16384).

start() ->
    do(),
    halt().

do() ->
    Bin = read(),
    io:format("~p~n", [byte_size(Bin)]).

read() ->
    ok = io:setopts(standard_io, [binary]),
    read(<<>>).

read(Acc) ->
    case file:read(standard_io, ?BLK_SIZE) of
        {ok, Data} ->
            read(<<Acc/bytes, Data/bytes>>);
        eof ->
            Acc
    end.
```

It works with invocation like:

```
erl -noshell -s p < input
```

Note both approaches could be used for line-oriented input using `{line, Max_Line_Size}` option for port or `file:read_line/1` for `file` module solution. Since version 17 (if I recall correctly) there is fixed performance bug in `file:read_line/1` I found so it is good now. Anyway, you should not expect performance and comfort of Perl.

Comment: @Hyney-pichi-Vychdil Your solution is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! It is true that [Steve's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37091420/49197) is more efficient but the difference is very small. I didn't know that one could refer inside an Erlang program to the standard input in this way. Very useful and also vey interesting. Thanks again. I hope your answer help more people having similar problems :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`open_port/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2) to open stdin and read binaries from it. For example:

```
-module(p).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    P = open_port({fd,0,1}, [in, binary]),
    Bin = read(P,<<>>),
    io:format("received ~p\n", [Bin]),
    halt(0).

read(P, Bin) ->
    receive
        {P, {data, Data}} ->
            read(P, <<Bin/binary, Data/binary>>);
        {'EXIT',P,_} ->
            Bin
    end.
```

The code has to trap exits so it knows to exit its reading loop when the port closes. This example reads everything into a single binary returned from the `read/2` function and then prints it out and exits, but obviously you can perform further operations on the binary in your actual application.

You can run this like this:

```
erl -noinput -s p < input
```

Comment: Your solution is very efficient, however it does not solve my problem because I cannot add the `noinput ` flag when calling from the external platform.

Comment: Your question shows that you're using `-noshell`. Why can you use that but you can't use `-noinput`? You really need to make your requirements clear in your question.

Comment: Because I can't select the flags used when running. I need it to solve a Hackerrank problem where performance when reading input is a must. I just click a button and wait for the results. Most of them finish due to timeout, and after profiling I discovered that the main time consumer was the input reading. Your proposed solution is amazingly efficient but unfortunately does not work in this context.